# Not able to successfully transform an xml doc to another.

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am trying to take this input

```
<root>
    <row>     
        <guestid>G1</guestid> 
        <splits>

            <split>
                <begin_date>2015-03-01</begin_date>
                <end_date>2016-06-30</end_date> 

                <apples>A01</apples>
                <oranges>BB01</oranges>
                <percent>60</percent>
            </split>

            <split>
                <apples>A02</apples>
                <oranges>BB02</oranges>
                <percent>40</percent>
           </split>

       </splits>
     <splits>
     <!-- No gap from previous. Starts the next day. -->
        <split>
            <begin_date>2015-07-01</begin_date>
            <end_date>2015-09-30</end_date>
            <apples>A55</apples>
            <oranges>BB55</oranges>
            <percent>75</percent>
        </split>

        <split>
            <begin_date>2015-07-01</begin_date>
            <end_date>2015-09-30</end_date>
            <apples>A100</apples>
            <oranges>BB100</oranges>
            <percent>25</percent>
        </split>
    </splits>

    <splits>
        <!-- There is a gap.(between 2015-10-01 and 2016-01-31 This will be filled up  with defaut splits.  -->
        <split>
            <begin_date>2016-02-01</begin_date>
            <end_date>2016-02-29</end_date>
            <apples>A777</apples>
            <oranges>BB777</oranges>
            <percent>85</percent>
        </split>

        <split>
            <begin_date>2016-02-01</begin_date>
            <end_date>2016-01-31</end_date>
            <apples>A200</apples>
            <oranges>BB200</oranges>
            <percent>15</percent>
        </split>
    </splits>

    <splits>
        <!-- There is a gap.(between 2015-10-01 and 2016-01-31 This will be filled up  with defaut splits.  -->
        <split>
            <begin_date>2016-04-01</begin_date>
            <end_date>2016-04-30</end_date>
            <apples>A777</apples>
            <oranges>BB777</oranges>
            <percent>85</percent>
        </split>

        <split>
            <begin_date>2016-04-01</begin_date>
            <end_date>2016-04-30</end_date>
            <apples>A200</apples>
            <oranges>BB200</oranges>
            <percent>15</percent>
        </split>
    </splits>



    <default_splits>

        <!-- no percentage. Will always be 100 percent. Never split. -->
        <default>>
            <begin_date>2015-01-01</begin_date>
            <apples>AD1111</apples>
            <oranges>BB1111</oranges>
        </default>

        <default>
            <begin_date>2015-07-01</begin_date> 
            <apples>A2222</apples>
            <oranges>BB2222</oranges>
        </default>

        <default>
            <begin_date>2015-11-01</begin_date>
            <apples>A8888</apples>
            <oranges>BB8888</oranges>

        </default>
    </default_splits>        

</row>

</root>
```

The split node is not necessarily sorted. The source xml has been presorted for each of reading.. The final result expected is as follows
However, the beging date and end dates within a splits node can be expected to be thhe same.

The end result expected is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Output XML -->

<root>
    <row>     
        <guestid>G1</guestid> 
        <splits>
          <!-- Reg -->
        <split>
            <begin_date>2015-03-01</begin_date>
            <end_date>2016-06-30</end_date> 

            <apples>A01</apples>
            <oranges>BB01</oranges>
            <percent>60</percent>
        </split>

        <split>
            <apples>A02</apples>
            <oranges>BB02</oranges>
            <percent>40</percent>
        </split>

    </splits>
    <splits>
        <!-- Reg no gap between prior split and this split. -->
        <split>
            <begin_date>2015-07-01</begin_date>
            <end_date>2015-09-30</end_date>
            <apples>A55</apples>
            <oranges>BB55</oranges>
            <percent>75</percent>
        </split>

        <split>
            <begin_date>2015-07-01</begin_date>
            <end_date>2015-09-30</end_date>
            <apples>A100</apples>
            <oranges>BB100</oranges>
            <percent>25</percent>
        </split>
    </splits>
    <!-- aded from default to cover the gap.-->
    <splits>
       <!-- based on default-->
         <!-- based on default -->
        <split>

            <begin_date>2015-10-01</begin_date>
            <end_date>2015-10-31</end_date>
            <apples>AD1111</apples>
            <oranges>BB1111</oranges>>
            <percent>100</percent>

        </split>
    </splits>

    <!-- added from the second default split. But ended before start of regular split. -->
    <splits>
        <!-- Default -->
        <split>

            <begin_date>2015-11-01</begin_date>
            <end_date>2016-01-31</end_date6
            <apples>A8888</apples>
            <oranges>BB8888</oranges>
             <percent>100</percent>

        </split>
    </splits>

    <splits>
        <!-- Reg -->
        <split>
            <begin_date>2016-02-01</begin_date>
            <end_date>2016-02-29</end_date>
            <apples>A777</apples>
            <oranges>BB777</oranges>
            <percent>85</percent>
        </split>

        <split>
            <begin_date>2016-02-01</begin_date>
            <end_date>2016-02-29</end_date>
            <apples>A200</apples>
            <oranges>BB200</oranges>
            <percent>15</percent>
        </split>
    </splits>

    <splits>
        <!-- Gap Filled up -->
        <!-- based on default -->
        <split>
            <begin_date>2016-03-01</begin_date>
            <end_date>2016-03-31</end_date>
            <apples>A8888</apples>
            <oranges>BB8888</oranges>
            <percent>100</percent>
        </split>
    </splits>


<splits>
    <!-- Reg -->       
        <split>
            <begin_date>2016-04-01</begin_date>
            <end_date>2016-04-30</end_date>
            <apples>A777</apples>
            <oranges>BB777</oranges>
            <percent>85</percent>
        </split>

        <split>
            <begin_date>22016-04-01</begin_date>
            <end_date>2016-04-30</end_date>
            <apples>A200</apples>
            <oranges>BB200</oranges>
            <percent>15</percent>
        </split>
    </splits>


    <!--added as there is an end date on last row. default values active to be used-->


    <splits>
         <!-- from default -->
        <split>
              <begin_date>2016-05-01</begin_date>
            <apples>A8888</apples>
            <oranges>BB8888</oranges>  
            <percent>100</percent>            
        </split>
    </splits>


</row>
```

I tred building the following. But am getting stuck due to an error condition.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:template match="/root/row">
    <row>
    <xsl:for-each  select="splits">
        <xsl:sort select="xs:date( split/begin_date[1])"  order="descending"/>

         <xsl:for-each select=".">
             <newsplit>
                 <begin_date><xsl:value-of select="begin_date" />               </begin_date>
                 <end_date><xsl:value-of select="end_date" /></end_date>
                 <apples><xsl:value-of select= "apples" /></apples>
                 <oranges><xsl:value-of select= "oranges" /></oranges>
                 <pct><xsl:value-of select= "percent" /></pct>
             </newsplit>
         </xsl:for-each>    

    </xsl:for-each>

    </row>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The error encountered is - A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value in 'cast as' expression [22]

I know I am still far away from completing this. But am stuck at this point.Will appreciate any feedback and help. 
Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to do use a `xsl:perform-sort` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-sorted-sequence).

Comment: Thanks will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as a `splits` has two child `split` elements with a `begin_date` your expression `xs:date( split/begin_date[1])` gives that error. To avoid that you could use `xs:date((split/begin_date)[1])`. I haven't really managed to understand the rest of the problem, so no idea whether that fix is helpful to solve your transformation problem.

Comment: Thanks Martin, thats the first issue. That did not work.